# a problem to Convert XML File dataset to JSON in python

Tags: python, json, xml, dataset, data-science-experience

I have been trying to convert a dataset file in XML format to JSON. I tried many solutions, I always got the same error

`ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 67667, column 103`

I tried `untangle`, `xmltodict`, `pandas_read_xml as pdx`

This is my code for  my attempt with `pandas_read_xml as pdx`  which was the last solution:

````
df = pdx.read_xml("Ryiadh_utf_8.xml")```
````

Comment: Parse your Ryiadh_utf_8.xml file through an XML validator. May you can use an online tool like xmlvalidation, to see if there are any errors in your XML file.

Comment: Please explain how you question is related to tag `data-science-experience` which you have used

Comment: Well, knowing the contents of your file will certainly help!